# Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter: can't save object

Tags: hibernate, spring

I encountered an common error with spring + hibernate, but can't fix it. I have 2 tables with one-to-many relation: each **Bsc** have many **Cell**

My hibernate config:

```
<class name="Bsc" table="bsc">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" />
    <set name="cells">
        <key column="bsc_id" />
        <one-to-many class="Cell" />
    </set>
</class>

    <class name="Cell" table="cell">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" />
    <many-to-one name="bsc" column="bsc_id" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

My dao:

```
public class BscDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements BscDao {

@Override
public Bsc get(int id) {
    return (Bsc) getHibernateTemplate().get(Bsc.class, id);
}

@Override
public void save(Bsc bsc) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(bsc);
}
}
```

My controller:

```
public class BscFormController extends SimpleFormController {

private BscDao bscDao;

public void setBscDao(BscDao bscDao) {
    this.bscDao = bscDao;
}

protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(id)) {
        return bscDao.get(new Integer(id));
    }

    return new Bsc();
}

public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {

    Bsc bsc = (Bsc) command;
    String success = getSuccessView();

    bscDao.save(bsc);

    return new ModelAndView(success);
}
}
```

In my view, I have a form to create/edit bsc info. In addition, I want list all cells of this bsc, so I config lazy load in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>mySessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

My problem: I can't save object when press Save button (it's saved ok if I remove OpenSessionInViewFilter config).

---

I have added TransactionManager config:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

But it still doesn't work. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved it setting the OpenSessionInViewFilter in the web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>lazyLoadingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
            <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
            <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure a TransactionManager in your Spring application context ?
By the way, if you're on a JDK5+, you'd better use annotations (you can decrease your code size by a 2 factor)

Comment: i use jboss server & hibernate annotation conflict with hibernate of jboss. and i see annotations slow than xml config (?)

Comment: i have added TransactionManager config

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

but it still dont work. I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm here because I'm encountering the same problem:  session.save(whatever) doesn't appear to actually persist the data to the database.  Debug logging shows a lot of selects, but no updates or inserts.

Calling session.flush() after the save() or update() or other methods forced the updates to be pushed to the database.

Why I HAVE to do this is what I haven't figured out yet.  I would have thought that eventually you'd want all updates to go to the database before the commit.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to set the flushmode so that there is a flush() before the final commit.  Nothing I've tried yet works, and an explicit flush call is still necessary.

Answer (score 0):

my current config

**web.xml**

```
<!-- lazyLoad-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>mySessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**spring config**

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* vn.com.vhc.cbs.dao.*.*(..))"
        advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" />
        <tx:method name="update*" />
        <tx:method name="remove*" />
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

hope this help